# three.js R71 - ambient removed, how configure to get same rendering results?

Tags: three.js, rendering, ambient

In [three.js r71 the `ambient` property has been removed from `THREE.Material`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r71).

Previously I used `ambient` to set correct rendering (lighting) effect of the materials that I used on my meshes. Now the appearance of all my meshes changed dramatically.

How can I get my materials rendered exactly as before r71?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here comes the why...

According to @WestLangley; I quote from [his post in the discussion](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6501#issuecomment-98491281) (link from @pprchsvr):

> `material.ambient` was the ambient reflectance of the material. For real-world objects, it should normally match `material.color`, the diffuse reflectance of the material. (Objects, after all, do not know where the photons came from.)
>
> We chose to simplify the API, and hardwire `material.ambient` to match `material.color`. Consequently, `material.ambient` has been removed.

This means you will no longer be able to set an ambient color that differs from the material color and there is as far as I know no "quick fix" to get the same rendering results for those materials as before.

---

- A possible solution would be to try make the material appear as before by tuning/changing the material color and the ambient lighting in your scene.
  See also the three.js documentation for [THREE.AmbientLight](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/lights/AmbientLight) and [THREE.MeshBasicMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshBasicMaterial) (and the other materials) for reference.
- Alternatively you could create your own shader material using [THREE.ShaderMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/ShaderMaterial) where you (re)create a shader that allows you to explicitly set an ambient color.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is discussed here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6501

Or you could override the r71 shader(s) with the earlier shader(s) (or just use the older version of three).